# Solved: Yum install of perl engages in circular logic

Tags: redhat, yum, perl

Edit: I'm an idiot and forgot to use createrepo and update the repodata, so the dependencies were not found on the repo.
Mystery solved.

---

Bit of an odd one.
I'm attempting to install perl on a Redhat box, and one would think it'd be as simple as just going

`yum install perl`

As the documentation suggests, but doing so results in output like the following:

```
---> Package perl.x86_64 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Socket) >= 1.3 for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Scalar::Util) >= 1.10 for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(threads::shared) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
...
---> Package perl-libs.x86_64 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6 will be installed
---> Package perl-macros.x86_64 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64 (rhel-cdn)
           Requires: perl(threads)
Error: Package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64 (rhel-cdn)
           Requires: perl(File::Spec::Unix)
Error: Package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64 (rhel-cdn)
           Requires: perl(Exporter)
Error: Package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64 (rhel-cdn)
           Requires: perl(Scalar::Util) >= 1.10
Error: Package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64 (rhel-cdn)
           Requires: perl(Socket)
Error: Package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64 (rhel-cdn)
           Requires: perl(Scalar::Util)
Error: Package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64 (rhel-cdn)
           Requires: perl(Getopt::Long)
...
```

Attempting to install these other packages fails too, as they depend on perl, which fails for the same reason; needing the perl extensions listed above.

Any pointers on possible causes?

Comment: Are all of the repos enabled?

Comment: See the edit, I had pulled in the perl dependencies needed on my repository server, but ran createrepo in the wrong directory, so it wasn't updated.